# Office js API - Resize Excel table

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I have a task pane add-in that allows to fetch data to a table within the worksheet (I'm loading values to a range within the table range). But whenever I get less data than the previous fetch, the table doesn't shrink to fit that new set of data.

There is any way I could resize a table using the Office js API? Or other alternative?

Cheers!

--------Edit--------

In a nutshell, this is the code I'm using. As the [documentation suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/performance#importing-data-into-tables), first I add data to a range and then I create a table for that range:

```
//Step 1: load data
await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
     const sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
     sheet.getRange(dataRangeAdress).values = data;
     await ctx.sync
});

//create table
await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
     const sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
     const table = sheet.tables.add(dataRangeAdress, true);
     await ctx.sync
});
```

And when I update, first I delete the previous data range like this:

```
 const dRange = sheet.getRange(dataRangeAdress);
 dRange.clear("Contents");
```

And then I repeat the Step 1 to load new data. I'm not using `table.getDataBodyRange()` to update the table due to the fact that occasionally I need to handle big sets of data (~15000 rows) and as the [documentations suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-core-concepts#read-or-write-to-a-large-range) I'm splitting into smaller subsets and loading as described on the Step 1 for each one.

When I get more data than the previous fetch, the table grows accordingly but when it's less doesn't shrinks.

[image]

Comment: The only way I can think of in which to shrink a table is to delete some of its rows. Why would shrinking be required while deleting rows is unacceptable? Please add the code you are using to your question.

Comment: @Variatus I didn't want to iterate over the table and delete empty rows because, as I described, occasionally I need to deal with big sets of data and I wanted to avoid to iterate over it. If I could just resize the table would be much more efficient.

Comment: Since you aren't retaining any existing data the easiest way should be to delete all data in the table, then the table itself, before pasting the new data and converting its range to a table. The sequence can be varied but the point is to delete the old and create a new table. Would that work for you?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is with iterating over rows. If you know the size of the previous data set and the current one, then you can calculate the number of rows from the bottom that are empty. You can then call delete on each of the rows (with a `for` loop that starts with the index of the last row in the table and then **decrements** the counter with each iteration). Your loop does not have to call context.sync on each iteration. You can call context.sync once after the loop has completed. There would be only one roundtrip to the document. Can you try this?

Comment: BTW, is there a reason that you are not using `Excel.run`?

Comment: @Variatus I tried that already but all the vlookups loses the reference whenever the table is deleted

Comment: You might reset the VLOOKUPs. Or you might use named ranges in the VLOOKUPs and then reset the RefersTo ranges of the Names. Also consider not deleting the ListObject entirely but to reduce it to a single row. Since you say your method expands the table correctly that should solve the problem.